# Date constructor return NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take value from input date box and store it in `Date` constructor to create new date. When i get that value with `val()` method i all time get NAN.

```
<input type="date" class="datepicker dp"  value="2016-03-10">
<input type="date" class="datepicker edp"  value="2016-03-15">

var start= $(".dp").val();
var end= $(".edp").val();

var date1 = new Date(start) 
var date2 = new Date(end);
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;

 // retruning
 alert(start) // 2016-03-10

 alert(date1) // Wed Mar 09 2016 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
 alert(date2) // Invalid Date
 alert(hours) // NAN
```

Comment: `date1.getTime()-......`

Comment: @RayonDabre subtracting one Date instance from another should work just fine. I notice that there's no `alert(date2)` - what is the value of `date2`?

Comment: `getTime()` return the some `NaN`

Comment: @Zend that means that the string you're trying to use to initialize `date2` is unrecognized. What's the value of `end`?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong comment earlier. I thought you are doing arithmetic operation over a string. After reading the question, I just understood it.

Comment: date2 return `Invalid Date` in alert...

Comment: This seems to be working: https://jsbin.com/firulejiro/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I guess you have more than just one element with class `edp`. Check what is value of `end`?!

Comment: Value of `end` is `2016-03-15`.. This example on jsbin is the some like main and copy paste return again NaN

Comment: `alert(date1)` return different date. He need to return from value date. Check comment

Comment: Ok i think this is because you are setting some date format to be different than the one you are using. What if you set `dp` value to `2016-03-13` instead of `2016-03-10`? If you have invalid date for `date1` then that's a format issue